# vba access 2010 update a filtered subform

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form with subform. The subform has the recordsource in a query named my_subform_query. The subform shows the query result and allow to filter the content with few comboBox in the father form.
The query source is a LEFT Join.
I need to update all records shown in subform but no the rest shown by the query.

How can I do this if the me.recordsource is the query my_subform_query

thanks in advance

edit: Sorry I want to mean to execute a update query with CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE table..." to update a True/false field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the parent form call:

```
Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form.Requery
```

From/in the subform itself call:

```
Me.Requery
```

To update, you would use the RecordsetClone of the subform:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form.RecordsetClone

While Not rs.EOF
    rs.Edit
        rs!YourTrueFalseFieldName.Value = True  ' or = False
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Wend

Set rs = Nothing
```

No requery of the subform will be needed.

Comment: It's ok? I marked the green V. This is my first answered question in stackOverflow!

Comment: Perfect. Have a nice weekend!